# What is this problem asking for?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know what exactly this problem is asking for.

**Problem:** A model for transport of a solute (moles of salt) and solvent (volume of water) across a permeable membrane has the form $$\dot{W}=A(k-\frac{M}{W}),\dot{M}=B(k-\frac{M}{W})$$

where $k$ is a parameter representing the bulk solute concentration and $A$ and $B$ are parameters that represent the permeability of the membrane.

(a) The water volume $W$ is a positive quantity. **Show that the system can be made linear by a reparametrization.**

(b) Determine the transformation between solutions of the linear and nonlinear systems.

What does it mean by transformation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reparametrization means changing the way the time is measured.

$$\frac d{ds}W(t(s))=\dot W(t(s))t'(s)=A(k-\tfrac MW)t'(s)$$
$$\frac d{ds}M(t(s))=\dot M(t(s))t'(s)=B(k-\tfrac MW)t'(s)$$

so if $t'(s)=W(t(s))$ can be arranged, the resulting system will be linear.

So start with the $s$-dependent functions $w(s),m(s),t(s)$ and the system

$$w'(s)=A(kw(s)-m(s))$$
$$m'(s)=B(kw(s)-m(s))$$
$$t'(s)=w(s)$$

Comment: No, I do not see how you arrive at those equations. What are $ξ$ and $ϵ$? b) is obtained by computing the inverse function of $t(s)$. Numerically, you solve the 3-dimensional system to obtain a table of trajecory points $(t,w,m)$ where you can now compute values of $W(t), M(t)$ by look-up and interpolation.

Comment: Why is the statement "so if $t′(s)=W(t(s))$ can be arranged, the resulting system will be linear" true? And why is $t'(s)=w(s)$? I ended up getting the solution, but it is not what I expected...

Comment: Obviously, in the end you need the inverse function $s(t)$ to get $W(t)=w(s(t))$ etc. For the inversion to work, the assumption that $W$ is and stays positive is essential. That $t'(s)=W(t(s))$ is just to get rid of the denominator. Fortunately, this also renders all other terms linear, so this is due to the special structure of the problem and not true in general.